# Por que no funciona Select2 cuando se combina con vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, select2

tengo este problema desde hace mucho tiempo, estoy usando laravel, vuejs 3 y select2, adicionalmente a eso estoy usando una plantilla gratuita que trabaja con laravel-vuejs3, la descargue porque no soy muy bueno para el front, pero no sabia que iba a tener este inconveniente, como puedo solucionarlo? gracias de atemano

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalproductcreate" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="">Crear Orden de Compra</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row col-md-12 mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="">Fecha de Orden de Compra</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                {{-- <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" v-model="newpurchase.date" :isReadOnly="readOnly"> --}}
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" v-model="newpurchase.date" v-bind:readonly="isReadOnly" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label>Proveedor</label>
                            {{-- <select class="form-select" id="supplier_id" name="supplier_id" v-model="newpurchase.supplier_id" required :disable="isReadOnly"> --}}
                            <select class="form-select" id="supplier_id" name="supplier_id" v-model="newpurchase.supplier_id"  v-bind:readonly="isReadOnly">
                                <option value="0" disabled>Proveedor</option>
                                @foreach($suppliers as $su)    
                                    <option value="{{ $su->id }}">{{ $su->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-md-12 mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label>Producto</label>
                            <select class="form-select select2" name="product_id" v-model="EditProductId" @change="selectproduct" required>
                                <option value="0" disabled>Producto</option>
                                <option v-for="pro in listproducts" :key="pro.id" :value="pro.id">@{{ pro.name }}</option>
                            </select>
                            
                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="form-label">Código del Producto</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" v-model="newpurchase.code"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-md-12 mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="form-label">Lote</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="batch" v-model="newpurchase.batch" @input="handleInputGeneric('minimum', newpurchase)" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="form-label">Fecha Caducidad</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_expiry" v-model="newpurchase.date_expiry" @input="handleInputGeneric('maximum', newpurchase)" min="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="form-label">Cantidad</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" v-model="newpurchase.amount"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-md-12 mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Precio Costo</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cost_price" v-model="newpurchase.cost_price" @input="handleInputGeneric('minimum', newpurchase)" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Ganancia %</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profit" v-model="newpurchase.profit"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Precio Venta</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sale_price" v-model="salePrice" readonly/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Precio Mayoreo</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wholesale_price" v-model="newpurchase.wholesale_price"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" @click="addnewproduct()">Agregar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="savenewpurchase">Guardar</button>
                  </div>
                  <div v-if="mostrar">
                    <table id="listado" class="table table-sm text-center">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Acción</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="(prod, index) in addproducts" :key="index">
                            <td>@{{ prod.product_id }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ prod.name }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ prod.amount }}</td>
                            <td class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="eliminarProducto(index)" style="width: 30px; height: 10px; font-size: 10px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
                                    Eliminar
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Modal de Creación -->
```

y tengo este codigo en mi layout principal:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap-5',
            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: que quiere decir que no funciona???

Comment: Cuál inconveniente? ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Inconveniente y problema es que no funciona el select2 y la pregunta es el por qué no funciona?

Comment: decir no funciona, no nos dice nada... puede ser que nisiquiera estes implementando selec2.... tienes que dar mas informacion sobre el error ... o comportamiento que tiene y cual era el esperado ... output de la consola etc ... sin esa informacion, no te podemos ayudar...

Comment: @MauEspaña `vue` carga las vistas/componentes después del `DOMContentLoaded`. En otras palabras, cuando se ejecuta el `ready` todavía el HTML devuelto por `vue` no existe y por eso no te funciona.

Comment: @Marcos y como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: @MauEspaña lo ideal sería que busques un componente `select2` para `vue3`